# Azure SQL Database adding WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-sql-database

I have created a Azure SQL Database with visual studio 2010, I have created  a web application and from there connect to Azure SQL Database with select * from SQL button and display in a gridview. However I need to develop a WCF from there. I have also created a WCF service application by right click on project solution and create. However I am stuck and do not know how to get started. Help pls ! Am I doing the right way to create a WCF from a Azure SQL Database?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection _SqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
    _SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:azqxk6h7dd.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDatabase;User ID=kailun92@azqxk6h7dd;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;";

    SqlCommand _SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM RecommendPlace", _SqlConnection);

    SqlDataAdapter _SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    _SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = _SqlCommand;

    DataTable _DataTable = new DataTable();
    _DataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    _SqlDataAdapter.Fill(_DataTable);
    GridView1.DataSource = _DataTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: This is now the 2nd wide-open question you've asked about this (first one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147171/add-wcf-service-into-azure-sql-database)). You really need to look at some of the docs and go through the samples, including ones in the [Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396) to ramp up on Azure. The code you show above is just a button handler opening a db and returning data, nothing to do with WCF. Spend time learning about WCF, then look at the WCF Web Role.

Comment: Also note that WCF and SQL Database are separate things entirely. A WCF service can certainly get its data from SQL Database, but they're independent. For WCF, it's all about the very specific view you want to offer to your client app (vs. giving the client app a database connection). You can even call your WCF service from your button-handler, helping you avoid burying SQL code there.

Comment: thanks for the tip I will do my reading on the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a WCF Service via the visual studio templates, then within this service you should generally add code to reference your SQL Server such as the code you have above.

Then create a client project as well that access those WCF functions of your service over the wire.

Start with this:

[Setting up WCF client that calls functions on your WCF Service.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651126.aspx)